# How to fix this regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am new to python and am currently learning `regex`, I tried the following code and some error occurred, can somebody please advised pleased.

```
#! python3
import re, pyperclip

phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''

((\d\d\d) | (\(\d\d\d\)))?
\s|- 
\d\d\d
- 
\d\d\d\d
((ext(\.)?\s)|x)
(\d{2,5}))? 

''', re.VERBOSE)


emailRegex = re.compile(r'''

[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+
@
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+

''',re.VERBOSE)


text = pyperclip.paste()
extractedPhone = phoneRegex.findall(text)
extractedemail = emailRegex.findall(text)

print(extractedphone)
print (extractedemail)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bane/Desktop/RegexProject.py", line 14, in <module>
    ''', re.VERBOSE)
  File "C:\Users\Bane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 234, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Bane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Bane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Bane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 944, in parse
    raise source.error("unbalanced parenthesis")
re.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 80 (line 9, column 10)
```

Document that I copied:

> President Dr. Barbara Jones x107 870-864-7190 brjones@southark.edu
>   Executive Assistant Ms. Susan Jordan x107 870-864-7190 sjordan@southark.edu
>   Vice President for Finance and Dr. Belinda Aaron x147 870-864-7122 baaron@southark.edu

Answer (score 0):

The error `line 9, column 10` points you to the offending regex line and char position.

You have an unmatched closing parenthesis.

```
(\d{2,5}))? <- the final closing parenthesis is missing an opening parenthesis
```

See https://regex101.com/r/BosI4u/1